# Test to check room broadcasting

Tags: unit-testing, socket.io, mocha.js

I have a test that checks if the `joined` event is emitted correctly when a users subscribe to a room.  However, I want to write a test to make sure when `chatUser2` joins `room2` that the `joined` event is only received by her and not `client1` in `room1`

How would I write a test to make sure `client1.on('joined')` is NOT called when `client2` connects?

```
var should = require('should'), 
io = require('socket.io-client'),
path = require('path'),
express = require(path.resolve('./config/lib/express')),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
sinon = require('sinon'),
app, agent, credentials, user, sale;

var chatUser1 = {'name':'Tom', 'room':'room1'};
var chatUser2 = {'name':'Sally', 'room':'room2'};


describe("Socket Server",function(){
    it('Should not broadcast joined event to unsubscribed rooms', function(done){

        var client1 = io.connect(socketURL, options);
        client1.on('connect', function(data){
            client1.emit('subscribe', chatUser1);

              client1.on('joined', function(data){
                data.should.equal(chatUser1.name + " has joined "+chatUser1.room);

                });

            var client2 = io.connect(socketURL, options);

            client2.on('connect', function(data){
              client2.emit('subscribe', chatUser2);
            });

            client2.on('joined', function(data){

                data.should.equal(chatUser2.name + " has joined "+chatUser2.room);
              client1.disconnect();
              client2.disconnect();
              done();
            });


        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was [here](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/01/28/testing-socketio-with-mocha-should-and-socketio-client/) #3

It's not really spying on anything, it just uses a variable to count the number of times the particular event is called.  In this case it should be only called once.

**test.js**

```
var should = require('should');
var io = require('socket.io-client');

var socketURL = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000';

var options ={
  transports: ['websocket'],
  'force new connection': true
};

var chatUser1 = {'name':'Tom'};
var chatUser2 = {'name':'Sally'};
var chatUser3 = {'name':'Dana'};

describe("Chat Server",function(){

it('Should be able to send private messages', function(done){
  var client1, client2, client3;
  var message = {to: chatUser1.name, txt:'Private Hello World'};
  var messages = 0;

  var completeTest = function(){
    messages.should.equal(1);
    client1.disconnect();
    client2.disconnect();
    client3.disconnect();
    done();
  };

  var checkPrivateMessage = function(client){
    client.on('private message', function(msg){
      message.txt.should.equal(msg.txt);
      msg.from.should.equal(chatUser3.name);
      messages++;
      if(client === client1){
        /* The first client has received the message
        we give some time to ensure that the others
        will not receive the same message. */
        setTimeout(completeTest, 40);
      };
    });
  };

  client1 = io.connect(socketURL, options);
  checkPrivateMessage(client1);

  client1.on('connect', function(data){
    client1.emit('connection name', chatUser1);
    client2 = io.connect(socketURL, options);
    checkPrivateMessage(client2);

    client2.on('connect', function(data){
      client2.emit('connection name', chatUser2);
      client3 = io.connect(socketURL, options);
      checkPrivateMessage(client3);

      client3.on('connect', function(data){
        client3.emit('connection name', chatUser3);
        client3.emit('private message', message)
      });
    });
  });
});

});
```

**app.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
var clients = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var userName;
  socket.on('connection name',function(user){
    userName = user.name;
    clients[user.name] = socket;
    io.sockets.emit('new user', user.name + " has joined.");
  });

  socket.on('message', function(msg){
    io.sockets.emit('message', msg);
  });

  socket.on('private message', function(msg){
    fromMsg = {from:userName, txt:msg.txt}
    clients[msg.to].emit('private message', fromMsg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    delete clients[userName];
  });
});
```